# Website Login And Scraping HTML

Tags: c#, authentication, web-scraping, httpwebrequest

I'm a little bit stuck here. I am busy making an Windows application that reads data from a website. However de website requires a login first and i don't seem to be able to get passes that.  I'm fairly new to programming, so i hope someone know a solution.

This is the code i use to login:

```
private void btnLogin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(LoginPageURL) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36";
        string postData = "j_username=" + number + "&j_password=" + password;
        byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        request = WebRequest.Create(Page2URL) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(httpResponse.Cookies);
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse2 = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(httpResponse2.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string result = stream.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Close();

        tbOutput2.Text = result;



    }
```

The point is that i get the HTML of the page after the login (Page2URL). But i keep getting the HTML from the Login Page.

Comment: Is the username and password form param correct? What does the response say?

Comment: I keep getting the HTML code of the login page instead of the page after login.
Should have mentioned that, i edited my post now :)

Comment: @user2722107 hi , have you succeed on this ? If yes please provide answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding cookies to the request from first response:

```
request.CookieContainer.Add(httpResponse.Cookies);
```

Probably the cookies in response are null! To cope up with this issue, read cookie values from response header and add them to the next request like this:

```
 string response_header_cookies = response.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie")    
 req.Headers.Add("Cookie",response_header_cookies);
```

In most of the cases this is the more efficient way. Hope this helps!
Source: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)